# Null key entry in a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

I'm facing a troubling situation.

I've got a dictionary which holds a null key entry...

[image: null key in dictionary]

This happens from time to time in my iis application, which then freezes when a lookup is performed on this dictionary (100% cpu, infinite loop):

[image]

Sources of FindEntry method (both uncompiled or [reference sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,bcd13bb775d408f1)) are pretty clear:

1) Having a null key in a dictionary is NOT possible

2) The infinite loop is pretty obvious given my dictionary private field:

[image: private fields]

Any idea on happens to me ?

ps: I do not have any funny thing installed like ryujit or custom .net build.
Just a regular iisexpress running under .Net 4.5

**edit**

As requested (i should have precised): I'm not doing anything funny with this dictionary either.
Only one usage:

```
  if (!readers.TryGetValue(type, out ret))
       readers[type] = ret = GetReaderOfTMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(this,null);
```

Comment: It would help if I could see your code.

Comment: @heh see my edit... but I doubt it will be usefull :/

Comment: This statement is not locked, though.

Comment: Is this dictionary accessed by more than one thread?

Comment: @JonHanna That's up to iis, but yes it could be :)

Comment: Well, is it stored somewhere static (or a member of something that is, or a member of a member...) or only created local to a method (or a member of something that is...)?

Comment: Yes, this very object can be reached by multiple threads. I'm realizing that must be a conccurrency issue on the this[] setter...

Comment: But that's very very unlikely since (as you can see) this dictionary has only 2 items oO

Comment: Yes, but quite possibly 2 items after 3 calls that inserted an item, 2 of which where simultaneous...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this dictionary isn't restricted to a single thread (created within a method and used there, but stored statically) then I'd expect this to happen.

`Dictionary` is written, like any other code, with assumptions about what can have previously happened to it. These assumptions don't consider simultaneous calls so e.g. it's assumed that if the dictionary is being resized, that the resize won't happen again until that resize is finished, that only one attempt will be made to set a given value at a time, and so on.

Don't guard against this, and two calls can put the dictionary into a state that its coders didn't consider and then things that don't make sense can happen, like having a null key even though null keys aren't allowed.

If such simultaneous use isn't going to be common (and it would seem it won't), then guard every access with a lock:

```
lock(lockObj)
  if (!readers.TryGetValue(type, out ret))
    readers[type] = ret = GetReaderOfTMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(this,null);
```

Where `lockObj` is an object at the same scope as `readers` which is used to lock all access to it. (Likely `readers` would work well as the lock object itself here, but when that is and isn't a good idea is another topic in itself).

If there are any other uses of `reader` they should also be locked using the same lock object.

If such simultaneous use is going be common then a concurrent dictionary that is designed to tolerate such uses would be better (`ConcurrentDictionary` in the framework, or my [`ThreadsafeDictionary`](https://bitbucket.org/JonHanna/ariadne/src/e4e6580d40f58c48feea8ff90436afce745f5975/Ariadne/Collections/ThreadSafeDictionary.cs?at=master) will both work). These tend to be less efficient generally, but more efficient above a certain level of concurrent uses.

Comment: replaced it with an immutable dictionary, actually :)

Comment: (since I dont care about losing a value i produce... this dictionary just acts as a cache)

Comment: @Olivier If it is a cache why not use real caches provided by the .NET framework. Either [`HttpContext.Current.Cache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [`MemoryCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you don't have access to `HttpContext.Current`

Comment: Not this kind of cache... A dictionary is perfect: I dont want this cache to be freed, it has a reasonable size and is called very often. The underlying method is generating some IL and I just dont want the same methods to be generated twice. They're not in a collectible assembly so that would even be dangerous.